# Configuração não aplicada ao inicializar o Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, servidor-de-aplicação

Estou com uma configuração especifica a ser realizada no `catalina.bat`, e esta configuração funciona perfeitamente quando inicio o servidor de aplicação através da execução do script `catalina.bat` (ou do `startup.bat`).

Contudo, ao iniciar o serviço do windows que executa o `Tomcat.exe`, a configuração não é aplicada, como se o script `catalina.bat` não fosse utilizado pelo `Tomcat.exe`.

Então, qual é a real diferença entre iniciar o servidor de aplicação com o `tomcat.exe` e o `catalina.bat/startup.bat`?

Ao executar o `tomcat.exe`, ele ignora as configurações de inicialização do `catalina.bat`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quando o tomcat é configurado como serviço do windows, o mesmo não executa o `catalina.bat` ou `startup.bat`.

Em vez disso, para adicionar novos parâmetros ao `java_opts`, deve-se seguir os passos abaixo.

1. Abrir a basta bin do tomcat
2. Executar no CMD o comando tomcat6w //ES//Nome_Do_Serviço_Do_Windows
3. Clicar na aba Java
4. Na caixa de texto java options, adicionar em cada linha o `java_opts` desejado.
5. Reiniciar o serviço para aplicar as alterações.

Answer (score -1):

Eu tive este problema e resolvi ele depois de apanhar muito eu percebi que o catalina.bat ou não era baixado ou ele era removido. Cheguei a esta conclusão após eu ter baixado o xampp que já vem com o tomcat e suas configurações. Depois que rodei a primeira vez o catalina foi excluido. Então eu desinstalei meu anti virus que era o avast security e baixei o xampp novamente. Na ide quando for localizar o servidor tomcat você o faz entrando pelo xampp e seu problçema será resolvido!!

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).